# An inequality of Huygens

Tags: inequalities

I am preparing a paper on Huygens' approximations to $\pi$ and I have to prove the following inequality: if $0 \le x\le \pi/2$ then
$$
\pi\ge \frac{\pi}{x}\sin(x)\bigl(20+51\cos(x)-2\cos^2(x)+6\cos^3(x)\bigr)/\bigl(21+18\cos(x)+36\cos^2(x)\bigr).
$$
The usual method of showing that the left hand side equals $\pi$ for $x=0$ and then trying to prove that it decreases for $x>0$ by proving that the derivative is negative is difficult since to apply the derivative is quite complex.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: The taylor expansion at x=0 is given by pi-pi x^6/175-O(x^8)

Comment: Maybe you missed a division sign between two brackets?

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Answer (score 3):

Using the substitutions
$$\tan\frac x2=t,\quad x=2\arctan t,\quad  \cos x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},\quad  \sin x=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}, $$
rewrite the inequality in question as
$$d(t):=\frac{2 t \left(39 t^6-29 t^4-95 t^2-75\right)}{3
   \left(t^2+1\right)^2 \left(13 t^4-10 t^2+25\right)}+2 \arctan t\ge0$$
for $t\in[0,1]$.

It remains to note that $d(0)=0$ and
$$d'(t)=\frac{128 t^6 \left(13 t^4+40 t^2+75\right)}{\left(t^2+1\right)^3
   \left(13 t^4-10 t^2+25\right)^2}\ge0$$
for all real $t$.